# Getting error "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

]Hey im getting this error :

```
   linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And its very strange because its to an app that is already on the app store and has no problems By mistake I removed all the references from the project package, but then putted them again and I'm getting this error... I don't know what it is , I have already searched this site for 100 solutions none of them worked, I even created did `pod init` on my file all over again but it still gives me this error. I also have a datamodel , I don't know if that's it , but please help me see why I'm getting this error. I am opening the app with the `xcworkspace` but still getting the error.

Please help me because I'm afraid I have lost my app forever, Im only 18 and I'm no cap crying, because I have spent the last 6 months doing this app, and now because of a stupid mistake like removing all references from a project I'm getting a bunch of errors and I'm afraid I might never get my app back.

[image]

[image]

[[image]][1

Comment: What's your Podfile? And the `pod install` is correctly done? Do you see the framework  in the Pods?

Comment: @Lamme, thanks for your fast response in Pods->Frameworks i only see red files, is that the problem ? how can i fix it ?

Comment: I have update a screenshot

Comment: "By mistake I removed all the references from the project package, but then putted them again and I'm getting this error..." Could you explain more that? Also, did you do the `pod install`? You talk about `pod init`, but that's clearly not downloading/adding the pods.

Comment: Yes i did pod install. By mistake i tried to remove a few files from my project and accidentally removed all the project references, i did "delete" -> "remove referees" , but then went to finder and added them again. But I start getting errors like this one

Answer (score 1):

Please just don't panic :). It can be solved. Here is the proposed solution. It should fix your problem:

1. do the `pod deintegrate`
2. if for some reasons the deintegration was messed up, remove anything that is still left from the list below:

   - the folder `Pods`
   - file `Podfile.lock`
   - the file `<yourApp>.xcworkspace`
3. run `pod install`
4. open the `.xcworkspace` file that was created.

It should've fixed all the `linker` errors that you had.

Let me know if there is anything else after these steps?

Comment: Thanks sir ! I have dont that and now I'm getting another error that is not the linker , it now says "Resumos xcworkspace issue" "Multiple commands produce /Users/pedrogouveia/lIbrary/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData"

Comment: Now just simply do `shift` + `command` + `K` (Clean Build Folder) and you're good to go!

Comment: Please update the question with the screenshot of the error that you get now. It is difficult to guess.

Comment: I have updated ! i double click the error but it doesn't show any details :(

Comment: You could press on the yellow Warning that is above the error. They are related. Did you add the Info.plist to the `Copy Bundle Resources` for your project?